# Contact Form 7 Redirect on Submit and if the first radio is checked

Tags: javascript, wordpress, redirect, contact-form-7

We fave a CF7 form http://prntscr.com/v3ijfm, http://prntscr.com/v3ilpi .
Website url : https://loyard.it/

The task:

If the first radio button is clicked and form is submitted, redirect the user to url.

For other 2 radio buttons a plugin handles the task (After successful payment user is redirected).

I inserted the js in functions.php but it's not working .

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'redirect_cf7');

function redirect_cf7()
{
    ?>
<script>
document.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', function(event) {
    $('#PayMeth input[name="radio-809"]').change(
        function() {
            if (this.checked && this.value == 'Paga alla consegna') {
                location = 'https://www.google.md/';
            }
        });
}, false);
</script>
```

Any suggestions ? Thanks in advance !

Update:  This works but the issue is its redirecting also for the other 2 radio buttons (

```
<script>
    $('body #PayMeth input[name="radio-809"][value="Paga alla consegna"]').attr('checked', true).change(
        document.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', function(event) {
            window.location.href = 'https://loyard.it/thank-you/';
        }, false));
    </script>
```

Comment: can you put console.log in function attached to event wpc7mailsent ... is this function even call ?

Comment: Its called but after wpcf7mailsent was triggered .It will redirect only after form was submitted then i click on first radio button . Clicking on the first radio button and then submitting the form does not work ...

Comment: @robert I need to check somehow : 1) Is radio button clicked ? 2) is form submitted ? If both conditions are met - redirect the user to the respective url ..

Comment: .attr('checked', true) ... you never remove redirect function if you once checked it ... you don't remove event callback function.... this can't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

f***ck this jQuery :P for me this is cleaner

```js
const redirect = () => {
   window.location.href = 'https://loyard.it/thank-you/';
};

const input = document.querySelector(`body #PayMeth input[name="radio-809"][value="Paga alla consegna"]`);
//console.log(input) - check that your selector works correctly
if(input){
  input.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
    if(event.target.value){
      document.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', redirect);
    } else {
      document.removeEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', redirect);
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is working ! =) . How can i remove this error in Console 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null `  ?

It happens on other pages https://prnt.sc/v3ne7v . Or maybe i should just enqueue this js code for the homepage only .

Comment: And i would highly appreciate if you tell me where did you learned JS ?))) I need to get better at it !

Comment: [Read this, this good fundamenatal](https://javascript.info/)

Comment: if(input){...input.addEventListner...} on the begin. that means that your selector don't match to any element on page.

Comment: Thank you very much - you helped me a lot ! I Your answer is correct .

Answer (score 0):

Change line

```
$('#PayMeth input[name="radio-809"]').change(
```

with

```
$('body #PayMeth input[name="radio-809"]').change(
```

Comment: https://prnt.sc/v3ki43, https://prnt.sc/v3kilf  unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: first remove js issue on your site.

Comment: i think i found the issue . It works only after i switch to another radio and then click again on the first one. So it's not working in real time - if it is already -chosen.

Comment: I need to check somehow :

1) Is radio button clicked ?
2) is form submitted  ?

If both conditions are met - redirect the user to the respective url ..

Comment: `$('body #PayMeth input[name="radio-809"][value="Paga alla consegna"]').attr('checked', true).change(
  document.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', function(event) {
   window.location.href = 'https://loyard.it/thank-you/';
  }, false));
`

This works but other radio buttons are also redirected (

What i am doing wrong https://prnt.sc/v3lyf9 ?

Comment: You need to use on Click event rather than change.